# rJava class not found exception

Tags: r, rjava

I'm just trying to get a simple example of accessing a custom java class from within R using rJava.

HelloWorld.java

```
class HelloWorld {
        public static void main(String[] args){
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
}
```

compiled .java to .class as such:

```
javac HelloWorld.java
```

R code (ran from same directory as HelloWorld.java and HelloWorld.class.

```
library(rJava)
> .jinit()
[1] 0
> .jnew("HelloWorld")
Error in .jnew("HelloWorld") : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

Thank you for any pointers.

Comment: Why do you want pointers?  Java uses references I thought...

Comment: hahaha, I see what you did there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're using a custom class you need to tell rJava where to find these custom classes.  One way to do this is to specify the location of your classes when you call jinit.

```
library(rJava)
# Assuming HelloWorld is in the current working directory
.jinit(".")
.jnew("HelloWorld")
```

I would recommend reading the help page for .jinit

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I was going through many examples of code and none of them specified a path to the custom classes :/ Will read up on these functions a bit more.