# Using the Stanford NLP libraries from within R, using the rJava package

Tags: java, r, stanford-nlp, rjava

Does anybody have any experience with using **StanfordCoreNLP** ( http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml through **rJava** in R?  I’ve been struggling to get it to work for two days now, and think I’ve exhausted Google and previous questions on StackOverflow.

Essentially I’m trying to use the StanfordNLP libraries from within R.  I have zero Java experience, but experience with other languages, so understand the basics about classes and objects etc.

From what I can see, the demo .java file that comes with the libraries seems to show that to use the classes from within Java, you’d import the libraries and then create a new object, along the lines of:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import edu.stanford.nlp.io.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;

    public class demo {

        etc.
        etc.

        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP();

        etc.
```

From within R, I’ve tried calling some standard java functions; this works fine, which makes me think it’s the way I’m trying to access the Stanford libraries that’s causing the issue.

I extracted the Stanford ZIP to **h:\stanfordcore**, so the .jar files are all in the root of this directory.  As well as the various other files contained in the zip, it contains the main .jar files:

- joda-time.jar
- stanford-corenlp-1.3.4.jar
- stanford-corenlp-1.3.4-javadoc.jar
- stanford-corenlp-1.3.4-models.jar
- joda-time-2.1-sources.jar
- jollyday-0.4.7-sources.jar
- stanford-corenlp-1.3.4-sources.jar
- xom.jar
- jollyday.jar

If I try to access the NLP tools from the command line, it works fine.

From within R, I initalized the JVM and set the classpath variable:

```
.jinit(classpath = " h:/stanfordcore", parameters = getOption("java.parameters"),silent = FALSE, force.init = TRUE)
```

After this, if I use the command

```
.jclassPath()
```

This shows that the directory containing the required .jar files has been added and gives this output in R:

**[1] "H:\RProject-2.15.1\library\rJava\java" "h:\ stanfordcore"**

However, when I try create a new object (not sure if this is the right Java terminology) I get an error.

I’ve tried creating the object in dozens of different ways (basically shooting in the dark though), but the most promising (simply because it seems to actually find the class is):

```
pipeline <- .jnew(class="edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP",check=TRUE,silent=FALSE)
```

I know this finds the class, because if I change the class parameter to something not listed in the API, I get a cannot find class error.

As it stands, however, I get the error:

**Error in .jnew(class = "edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP", check = TRUE,  : 
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP**

My Googling indicates that this might be something to do with not finding a required .jar file, but I’m completely stuck.  Am I missing something obvious?

If anyone can point me even a little in the right direction, I’d be incredibly grateful.

Thanks in advance!

Peter

Comment: No but I have had good success with openNLP which seems to do what you're after: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openNLP/openNLP.pdf.  Between this and the `tm` package I think you'll have a bunch of tools that have been tested and work with R rather easily.

Comment: I have no rjava experience and my first attempt also failed. (I did see in the rjava help that it recommended using .jpackage, not .jinit as you are.) But this is just the generic error when a class can't be found. Your problem doesn't appear specific to StanfordCoreNLP, but rather a matter of learning how to get rjava to load any external library in a jar file....

Comment: Thanks @TylerRinker.  I actually already have a setup that uses tm, OpenNLP and Wordnet, which does work well.  However, for my new project I really need a syntactic parser, which appears to still be in the experimental stage with OpenNLP (at least what the docs say on their website).  The Stanford libraries have a great parser, which includes pre-trained models, so it would be perfect if I could get it to work with R...

Comment: @ChristopherManning: Thanks for that.  However, I've just tried calling an external 'hello world' class (as in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106061/rjava-class-not-found-exception?rq=1) and it works fine, so maybe there's something I have to do slightly differently with the more complex structure of the .jar file (although I've also tried extracting the .jar file and referencing the class file directly, and still the same error)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your classpath is wrong - you are using a directory but you have JAR files. You have to either unpack all JAR files in the directory you specify (unusual) or you have to add all the JAR files to the class path (more common). [And you'll have to fix your typos, obviously, but I assume those come form the fact that you were not using copy/paste]

PS: please use [stats-rosuda-devel](http://mailman.rz.uni-augsburg.de/mailman/listinfo/stats-rosuda-devel) mailing list if you want more timely answers.

Comment: Thank you! I had tried adding the StanfordCore JAR file to the classpath directly, but didn't realise that I also needed to add the other JARs...  Rather naive of me I guess. I just tested my R code with the correct classpath and it's now working, so thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Success!

After hours of tinkering, I managed to find a work-around.  If anyone is interested, this is what I did:

- Using Eclipse, I started a new project.
- I then created a directory called ‘lib’ under the root of the project and copied all the Stanford .jar files into this directory.
- After this, I edited the properties of the project in Eclipse, went to ‘Java Build Path’, clicked the libraries tab.
- I then choose to import the Java system libraries.
- I also clicked ‘Add External Jars’ and selected all the Stanford jars from the lib directory.
- I then created intetermediary Java classes to call the Stanford classes (rather than trying to call them directly from R).

Example:

```
import java.lang.Object;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import edu.stanford.nlp.io.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;


public class NLP {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("annotators", "tokenize");
        StanfordCoreNLP coreNLP = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
      }

}
```

This doesn’t return anything, but shows how a Stanford object can be created.

- Build the project using Eclipse.
- From within R, then set the working directory to the Java project's /bin directory (this isn’t strictly necessary, as you can add the classpath directory instead, but it simplifies things).

Then the object can be created in R with:

```
.jinit(classpath = ".")    // This initilizes the JVM
obj = .jnew("NLP")
```

After this any methods you’ve created within the intermediary java classes can be called with:

```
Name_of_var_to_store_return_value = . jcall(class name, signature type, method, paramters)
```

I still didn’t figure out why I can’t call the Stanford classes directly from R, but this method works.  I suspect that @ChristopherManning is right and my problem is down to calling the external jar from R.  By building it from scratch, the Stanford jars are linked during the build, so I guess that’s what fixed it.